# Formulation of a SDP problem in a standard form with constraints on blocks

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have a semidefinite problem, 
\begin{align}
\min_{\beta,\eta,R} &t\notag\\
\textrm{s.t.} & \beta ,\eta \geq 0\notag\\
&\Bigl[\begin{matrix}
K\odot R&&1+\eta-\beta\\
(1+\eta-\beta)^\mathsf{T}&(t-\eta^\mathsf{T} a -\beta^\mathsf{T} b)
\end{matrix}\Bigr] \succcurlyeq 0\notag\\
& R \succcurlyeq 0\notag\\
&\langle R,e_i e_j^\mathsf{T} \rangle = h_{ij},\forall i,j \epsilon H\notag\\
\end{align}
where $\odot$ is the matrix hadamard (element-wise) product, and $\langle R,e_i e_j^\mathsf{T} \rangle =trace(R^\mathsf{T} e_i e_j^\mathsf{t}) $.
I want to code this problem using any of standard solvers, esp,MOSEK. But these solvers accept the problem in a standard format. How to convert this problem to a standard SDP formulations such as the standard form for mosk? 
(I need to code it directly in a standard solver, and not using YALIMP or CVX.)

Comment: You should define your notation a bit. Is $\odot$ the element wise Hardamard product? Is the left hand side of the last row of the problem the trace of the matrix product?

Comment: ⊙  is the hadamard product, and the last row is the trace of the matrix product. I add this definition of notations.